# Python: variable only works when print statement is present

Tags: python, wxpython, wxformbuilder

I have an extremely strange problem that has stumped me for about the past day.

```
import wx, gui, threading, time, pyodbc
from OrderNumEntry import entryID, plyID, stationID
from main import strPlyDB
from Op1Login import eID1
global eID1

class MainFrame1(gui.MainFrame1Op):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        gui.MainFrame1Op.__init__(self, parent)
        self.m_textCtrl3.SetValue(eID1)
        # print eID1

    def checkClick1(self, event):
        if threading.activeCount() < 2:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.checkAdvance1)
            t1.setDaemon(True)
            t1.start()
            self.m_checkBox110.SetValue(True)

    def checkAdvance1(self):
        strODBC_conn = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s' % strPlyDB
        conn = pyodbc.connect(strODBC_conn)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # eID1 = '00839530'
        print 'test1'
        print eID1
        print 'test2'

        SQL = 'INSERT INTO tblRecord(EntryID, PlyID, StationID, EmployeeNum, BuyoffTime) values(?,?,?,?,?)'
        cursor.execute(SQL, (entryID, plyID, stationID, eID1, time.strftime("%c")))

        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

What's going on is there's a primary Python file `main.py` that initializes my `mainframe1` class, which references `gui.py` for all of its wxpython code to bring up the window. This file is simply the event handler. `checkClick1` runs when I click on a check box in my window (creative name I know), which in turn starts a thread for `checkAdvance1`.

Everything works fine in the program except for one part. My `eID1` variable works just fine in `__init__`, and `textCtrl3` displays it. However, when I try and use it again in `checkAdvance1`, the program hangs.

To test it, I surrounded the print statement for `eID1` with two test print statements. Only `test1` is printed, and no error code is given, the program simply hangs. To make matters even more confusing, when I put a `print eID1` statement in the `__init__` function (it's commented out right now), the program runs just fine!

I'm not sure how variable functionality could be affected by a print statement, but it's happening. However, putting a print statement in to fix it seems like a shoddy workaround that ignores the actual problem. Also, the commented-out `eID1` declaration is just an example to show you what the content of the variable looks like when the program is running.

EDIT:
I have come up with a work around that I'm not entirely satisfied with, but it's better than adding print. If I create another variable, I can set it to the string translation of empID1, like so: `empID1 = str(eID1)`. I can then reference this value later in place of eID1. However, this still doesn't sit well with me, as according to everything I know and have researched, my original code SHOULD work. It makes me feel like there's something bad going on behind the scenes that could come back to bite me later.

Comment: I tried it again with "global eID1" in the first line of both functions and it still hangs. What bothers me the most is that there's no error code. If eID1 was undefined, it would tell me so. But it isn't, and it just stops working with no explanation or clue why.

Comment: What `type` does `eID1` have?

Comment: The fact that `checkAdvance1` is run via a thread seems relevant. Some sort of deadlock issue?

Comment: By the way, `global` statements are only necessary in functions that need to modify a global. Using it at the module level is meaningless.

Comment: Checked and the `type` is `unicode`

Comment: @chepner, I use a thread because without it, any parameters of `m_checkBox110` can't be changed until the event code finishes. I needed it to disable and display a check immediately, but I also need to run about 100 lines of code off of that single event, including a `time.sleep(.5)`. So in order to do that, I just did some essentials in `checkClick1` and ran everything else in a thread.

Comment: You don't access anything wx from the thread?

Is it o.k. to pass Unicode to cursor.execute or should it be a string?

Comment: @Werner What do you mean by accessing wx from my thread? And as far as unicode and SQL goes, I'm not sure, but I can't even get to that part of my code because the print statement checking to see if my variable is valid hangs the code. Needless to say if I take out the `print` statement instead of hanging there it just hangs on the SQL statement

Comment: Re wx and thread, in your sample 'checkAdvance1' you don't do not access wx, i.e. doing something like You should "self.m_checkBox110.SetValue(True)" should not be done, so I wonder if above is your actual code or a reduced sample.

Comment: Could the problem be that you access a global from the thread?  What about passing it in when you start the thread.  Still does not explain why adding a print statement would fix it.

Comment: Is there a conflict in variable and what you are expecting                            from Op1Login import eID1 and                                       
global eID1

Comment: Werner, this is a reduced sample of my code. I just put in what's needed here, so if something aside from my `eID1` issues looks like it doesn't work, trust me, it does. And I am able to access other variables in my thread so it can't be that.

@user3203010 I am expecting to import an 8 digit string of numbers, such as `'00839634'`. It's importing it successfully, as `self.m_textCtrl3.SetValue(eID1)` works fine. However, when I try to reference it later in the program, it hangs. Also, I've just made an edit to my question with a few more details.

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas? I fixed it by passing `str(eID1)` instead of just `eID1`, but this still makes me uncomfortable. This code needs to be bulletproof. It's starting to look a lot like a bug, unless anyone else has any insight. If so, where can I report it?

Comment: Please create a small runnable sample program that demonstrates the issue. I don't think we have enough information to give a valid diagnosis at this point. Knowing which OS, Python and wxPython version might be helpful as well.